# Updating multiple objects from a template in Django

Tags: django

It might have been asked before but I cannot find the link.

I am completely new to Django (just 1 day) so you guys might want to provide me with links that are for rookies.

I am trying to get people to vote on Dishes they have eaten at different places. I have a list of dishes and restaurants. Now I want users to connect the dish to restaurant and rate the dish. I am picking three dishes at a time in paginated form from DB and showing them to user and asking him to enter of 3 restaurants for each dish along with his rating. I am using custom HTML and CSS written by my designer guy. UI looks something like this:

[image]

Now I have only one save button on a page. A user might enter only one restaurant or all three, he also might not enter anything for any of the dish.

My views are defined as:

```
    from django.db import models

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_line1 = models.CharField('Address Line 1', max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    add_line2 = models.CharField('Address Line 2', max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have just written one view to display the dishes

```
from DishoomIt.models import Dish
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage


def index(request):
    dishes_list = Dish.objects.all().order_by('name')
    paginator = Paginator(dishes_list, 3)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except:
        page = 1

    try:
        dishes = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        dishes = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render_to_response('dishoom_templates/index.html', {'dishes':dishes, 'num_pages': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

On template side, I am using a for loop to show three dishes on one page

Now my question is when user enters values in these fields and hits Save button, how do I update all the objects at once?

I have read about saving one item but I am completely confused on how to pass multiple objects and save.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the django documentation at [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets). They're useful for exactly this.

Comment: Thanks a ton! When you have just one day to learn and another day to go live, people like you are life savers :)

Comment: See also the specific documentation on [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)